# Angular: How to subscribe to child path in parent component?

Tags: angular

I have the following routes in my module:

```
const userManagementRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'userManagement',
    component: UserManagementComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'users',
        component: UsersComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'user-groups',
        component: UserGroupsComponent
      },
      ... (many other routes)
  }
];
```

I would like to subscribe to the URL in the parent component, such that the parent will know when a child is rendered. E.g.: when the URL changes from

```
http://localhost:4200/userManagement/users
```

to

```
 http://localhost:4200/userManagement/user-groups
```

the parent should know.

I tried to to the following, but neither of these approaches don't work:

```
export class UserManagementComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.firstChild.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params);
    });

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params);
    });

    this.route.url.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to router events like so:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        const currentUrl = event.url;
      }
    });
```

This will notify you every time a route change occurs. Though keep in mind this is all router events, not just child route changes.

Hope this helps.

Kind regards Chris

Comment: Thanks! But, I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution. I feel it must be a better approach

Comment: There may be, but this is what i currently use to achieve the same. You can do a check on current url to see if it contains your parent url, then do the math. I think this is a fair example, though not as clean as ideally subscribing to the parent route and listen for child routes become active. Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

As per this issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11692), there is no direct solution to what you are looking for. But a workaround, that watches out for each route change and then you may check if that is the first child or so.

Copying the same code here

```
this._router.events
      .pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        switchMap(
          () =>
            (this._route.firstChild && this._route.firstChild.params) ||
            observableOf({}),
        ),
      )
      .subscribe(params => console.log(params));
```